# Salesforce Marketing Cloud Data Stream OR Data Source

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, data-synchronization

I'm currently setting up an SF -- MC integration. The Connector is already installed and is working.

Now I face following issue/questions.

I could use:

1. **Data Stream** feature streams Salesforce OBJECT Data into Marketing cloud.
2. **Data Source** let you use information from Sales Cloud and Service Cloud sources as part of your marketing activities

For writing data Back I would use a Salesforce Data Extension.

When should I use **Data Stream** and when should use **Data Source**?

It's quiet confusing when setting it up for the first time.
Hoe anybody is able to help me out.

Thank you.
Paul.

Comment: Where are you getting the information from that data stream doesn't let you use personalization for marketing?

Answer (score 1):

Paul,

I think part of your confusion is the ever-changing terminology and methodology of Marketing Cloud.

Data Stream is the broad term for the connectivity between Salesforce (Sales & Service Clouds) and Marketing Cloud. "Synchronized Data Extensions" is a feature located under "Data Sources" in the Contact Builder app. "Synchronized Data Extensions" is one way to access Salesforce data in Marketing Cloud. That data can be updated as often as every 15 minutes.

[Synchronized Data Sources reference](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/features/synchronized_data_sources/)

But, this connectivity via Data Stream (and Synchronized Data Extensions) only moves in one direction--from Salesforce to Marketing Cloud.

To send data from Marketing Cloud to Salesforce, you need to use "Sales & Service Cloud" activities in a Journey or use AMPScript in a Landing Page or Email.

[Sales & Service Cloud Canvas Activities reference](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/sales_and_service_cloud_canvas_activities/)

[AMPScript reference for updating a Salesforce record](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/updatesinglesalesforceobject.htm)

The documentation should give you a place to start. StackExchange and Marketing Cloud support can help fill in the gaps. Feel free to reach out to me and we can set up a call if you think that would help.

--Karl